# FIlter search across application in rails when any of the entity is disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an rails application which is quite big with many controllers (entities)
I added a feature of enable and disabling of each entity which means that those which are disabled are not shown from view wise ..

Now my problem is

```
          I have entities like A,B,C
            A has B as foreign key
```

On A's controller there are many places where A will do a search of A's entries on the whole.

How to filter the search of A's entries when B is disabled.
My table structure is

```
                     A(id,category_type,category_id)
```

where category_id is the foreign key of B's id

Please give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In model A,

While you write the relation, you can specify like this ..

belongs_to :category, :conditions => {:enabled => true}

Comment: @srikanth- i am saving whether category is enabled or not in a separate table Settings(id , name,value) where value holds t/f for category